# HTML element doesnt contain all page contents

Tags: html, css

I am new to html/css and I'm working on a webpage that is coming along ok except for an issue with the div wrapper/footer. My HTML/CSS elements are not spanning the entirety of the page vertically, only the initial viewport of the window they open in. As a result, my  wrapper is similarly constrained, and ultimately my footer is incorrectly placed (it should follow the mainsec element). I have spent hours reading html/css books and forum posts and the issue persists! Oddly enough, I was able to get the html/body elements to work right but the div was still stuck, and now they're all screwed up again for unknown reasons.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <header id = "head">
    </header>
    <article class = "mainsec">
        <section class = "info">
            <h2>Topic</h2>
            <hr style = "width: 80%">
            <p>content...</p>
            <h4>Tools</h4>
            <dl>
                <dt>- Description</dt>
                <dd><a href="#">tool</a></dd>
            </dl>
        </section>
        <section class = "di">
            <h2>Integrations</h2>
            <hr style = "width: 80%">
            <h4>Integration 1</h4>
            <dl>
                <dt>- Description</dt>
                <dd><a href="#">link</a></dd>
            </dl>
        </section>
    </article>
    <footer id = "foot">
            <p style = "font-size : 16px;font-family : helvetica;text-align:center">DIEM: Data Integration Expectation Map  Contact: ...</p>
    </footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html, body, div, 
article, footer, header,section{
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section, body {
  display: block;
}

html{
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    position:absolute;
}
body {
    position: absolute;
    line-height: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    background-color: gray;
    clear: both;
}
/* still not sure how containment clearing works so ill leave this here */
.q:before,
.q:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
.q:after {
  clear: both;
}
.q {
  clear: both;
  *zoom: 1;
}

#head{
    position:sticky;
/*     background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right bottom,#646464, #c2c2c2);
    background:    -moz-linear-gradient(to right bottom,#646464, #c2c2c2);
    background:         linear-gradient(to right bottom,#646464, #c2c2c2); */
    text-align: center;
    height:66px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    box-shadow:0px 1px 5px #494949;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: white;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}

.mainsec {
    background-color: beige; 
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px black;
    position: absolute;
    top: 90px;
    left: 100px;
    width: 90%;
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}

#foot{
    display:block;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to bottom right,#c2c2c2, #646464);
    background:    -moz-linear-gradient(to bottom right,#c2c2c2, #646464);
    background:         linear-gradient(to bottom right,#c2c2c2, #646464);
    margin-top:15px;
    width: 100%;
    bottom:0;
    position: absolute;
}

#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 0px;
    clear: both;
  }
```

Help! I've removed a lot of code for readability that shouldnt really matter here fyi (and tested that the error persists with just this code).

Comment: What does this have to do with javascript?

Comment: too many absolute positioned elements fighting for space. I think you are not familiar of the purpose and options on position. One of the quickest fix, if that is what you like, is to change the position:absolute to position:fixed on your footer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Ill be honest. This has nothing to do with Javascript. I'd advise removing that tag.**

So you want something to fit vertically!?

Well `100%` only correlates to a wrapper div of a set size. Ie if the wrapper is 700px height then the inner at `100%` will become `700px`

Enter `viewheight`. Change a div element to `65vh` it will adjust completely to the size of the window. But not full height.

> **Note** however that `viewwidth` doesn't take into consideration the scroll bar.

The same can be done with `vw` like so:

```
#div {
 Background-color: blue;
 Width: 100vh;
 Height: 100vw;
}
```

If your concerned about contrast between different screen sizes then you want to look at `meta viewport`

***It isn't necessary to set the html or body too 100%.***

Another thing is your sheer amount of positions. 
Not everything needs to be `absolute`. `Absolute` is used to float something outside normal constraints. A tip though. A div that's `position absolute`, inside another div that's `relative` can only move within that div wrapper. Unless you force it to go out side with position moves like `top`, `left`, `right`, `bottom`

> in reference to the footer issue. You can do `position fixed`. Or `relative`.

Position absolute is for placing things in specific locations. Removing the position all togeather on both mainsec and foot will make them follow after each other the positions aren't necessary

**Further reading**

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp

Comment: Thanks for your help, I learned a lot from your post and I was not aware of the vh and vw units. Sorry about the Javascript tag issue I forgot the rules of the forum.

Comment: That's okay. If it awnsered you question. Make sure you tick it off.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like place a meta viewport tag in the head would help.
A  viewport element gives the browser instructions on how to control the page's dimensions and scaling.

The width=device-width part sets the width of the page to follow the screen-width of the device (which will vary depending on the device).

The initial-scale=1.0 part sets the initial zoom level when the page is first loaded by the browser.

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

<title>Title Goes Here</title>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<link rel="stylesheet/less" href="less/style.less">
<script src="js/libs/less-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I do have that included in my head tag, sorry for omitting that detail.